# Is creating an @string resource convention in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and java in general (been teaching myself for the last year) and I found out pretty early on that I didn't have to create a string resource when putting text on views and things in the same nature. I was wondering what the convention is on that and if it will cause me any problems down the road. I'm sorry if this isn't the place to be asking this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A code example might help, or at least more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using string resources (or ResourceBundle) is not strictly necessary, but is very useful later on when you need to translate to different languages (you just send the resource for translation, instead of having to hunt down places in the code) and also allow you to change strings based on a user's locale.